# Material-UI DropZone "getFileAddedMessage" handler returning multiple file names in a single string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, dropzone, react-dropzone

I am using Material UI dropzone. https://yuvaleros.github.io/material-ui-dropzone/. I am able to drop multiple files at a time. But the component is returning all file names combined in a string on the snack bar alerts. I want to have separate snack bar alerts for each file when uploading multiple files.

any suggestions or thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the Material UI Dropzone library doesn't give you access to have multiple snack bar alerts, but you can achieve this using the `onDrop` property and a customized snackbar library (you can use the one from the material example - at the bottom of the snackbars page there is an example on using the notistack lib: https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/).

A few notes:

1. You need to remove the `getFileAddedMessage` method (you are not going to use it).
2. You need to set `showAlerts` to `false` (because you manage the alerts manually and not using the Material UI Dropzone lib.

Here is an example of the DropzoneArea:

```
<DropzoneArea
    acceptedFiles={["image/*", "video/*", "application/*"]}
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
    showFileNames
    filesLimit={20}
    showAlerts={false}
    onDrop={e => {
      e.forEach(item => this.props.enqueueSnackbar(item.name));
    }}
/>
```

You can see a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-material-dropzone-multiple-snackbars-54rij?file=/src/index.js

Comment: An absolutely MASSIVE oversight from mui-dropzone. It almost entirely eliminates the benefit of multiple uploads. I really wish they'd expose that.

Comment: This is awesome. I love your codeSandbox. It worked perfectly for me. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `alertSnackbarProps` prop

like this:
<DropzoneArea
showAlerts={true}
alertSnackbarProps={{anchorOrigin:{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'center' }}}
/>